# Run Flink 1.5.1 with current version of AWS EMR (using 1.5.0)

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-flink, amazon-emr

Flink 1.5.0 has a bug that has been fixed in 1.5.1.  We'd like to use 1.5.1 with the EMR but the latest version(emr-5.16.0) only has the option of flink 1.5.0..

Is there a means for me to use 1.5.1 with this version of the EMR?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See the documentation [here](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.6/ops/deployment/aws.html#custom-emr-installation) for instructions on installing a custom Flink version on EMR.